# Convert ISO8601 date time format in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, iso8601

I am requesting a list of objects from Salesforce via the Restforce API in my Rails 4 application. When I request the date and time field on each object, I receive in in iso8601 format. For example, in my view, the date and time are displayed like this:

```
2014-10-03T22:37:15.000+0000
```

In my view I have:

```
<td><%= transaction.Recorded_On__c %></td>
```

I would like to be able to somehow call strftime on Recorded_On__c however, I get a undefined method error when I do that currently. I've also tried date_select(transaction.Recorded_On__c) and receive syntax errors.
In the end I would like to have the date displayed as month("Feb"), day("20"), year("2014)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert string to date or time and then - use I18n.l method to specify needed format.

```
<td><%= I18n.l "2014-10-04T22:49:02+04:00".to_time, format: "%b.%d.%Y" %></td>
```

Comment: I set transaction.Recorded_On__c to a variable and then used variable.to_time as you suggested above. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use I18n, you have to create en.yml that you can find here:

[I18n Rails](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml)

`<td><%= l transaction.Recorded_On__c.to_date, format: :long  %></td>`